# Sequencing of transaction between jsp page(the view) and the servlet (Controller)

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm working with servlets for a while, and trying to figure out how the view communicate with the servlet, to be more accurate I'm talking about the instances of the :
HttpSession, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse classes.

1) In my jsp file i have this line of code :

`<% CategorieForm cf=(CategorieForm)session.getAttribute("catForm");%>`

and this is the first appearance of 'session' in this file.

when this session object is been created.

2) also in my servlet i have this method :

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
/*
code that get the resuest parameters using the 'request.getParameter()' method, calls   the model ans store the results in formBean
*/
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("catForm",cf);
response.sendRedirect("Categories.jsp");
}
```

I'm just trying to understand how this works, the sequencing of transactions between view and servlet, when the objects 'request' and 'response' are created, is the HttpSession object in the servlet is the same as the session in the jsp file.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the browser. It generates and sends a POST request.

That POST request is received, as bytes, by your Servlet container (YMMV). The Servlet container parses it, generates `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects, finds the appropriate `Servlet` to handle the request, and pulls a `Thread` from its HTTP worker thread pool to run it in.

It dispatches the `Thread` which invokes `service(..)` on your `Servlet`. Your custom `Servlet` extends `HttpServlet` and so inherits its `service()` method which, depending on the request, calls one of the `doXXX()` method.

In this case, `doPost()` will be invoked. When you reach

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
```

if an `HttpSession` doesn't exist, the `Servlet` container will create one for you and add a JSESSIONID Cookie to the `HttpServletResponse`.

When you then do

```
response.sendRedirect("Categories.jsp");
```

The Servlet container will commit the response with a status code of 302 and a `Location` header containing the URI to `Categories.jsp` resolved against your host and context path.

If your client is a browser, it will most likely send a new GET request to that URI. Your Servlet container will do the same thing I described above and invoke `service()` on the compiled class generated from your `jsp` file. This will produce the body of the HTTP response which will be sent back to the client.

Comment: Woow that's a great answer, exactly what i was looking for thanks, I'm sorry that some viewer wasn't as good as you guys, he just voted down and asked to close the question.

Comment: @Hossam You're welcome. That happens. It's harder when they don't provide a comment.

Answer (score 2):

> when this session object is been created.

Session is created when request is made for the first time with no associated session

> I'm just trying to understand how this works, the sequencing of transactions between view and servlet, when the objects 'request' and 'response' are created, is the HttpSession object in the servlet is the same as the session in the jsp file.

in that code snippet you are setting some attribute to session and then redirecting user to  `Categories.jsp`

Comment: man that's great, but please correct me if I'm wrong
the jsp file is the first to be executed, after that it sends the request to the servlet, then the servlet creates the session right?
So how that comes that i have this line 
`<% CategorieForm cf=(CategorieForm)session.getAttribute("catForm");%>` in my jsp file

Comment: server creates session instance for you on first request, regardless of jsp/servlet

Answer (score 1):

Upon the very first request from a user session is created. Session behaves like a hashmap and can store key/value pairs. The session also has an ID. Once the session is created, server asks client to create a cookie with session ID (there is an alternative if cookies are not available).

On each subsequent request server uses that cookie to figure out which session object to use. So yes, when you work with a session changes will persist as long as the session is not expired.

Comment: So the session is created on the jsp file, or in the servlet like jigar said ?

Comment: @HossamOukli Session is created in server's internals when server receives a request with no session information. It doesn't matter when it's created when you're working with servlet or JSPs. In this case you can just assume that it's always available and one client is associated with one session. And BTW, JSP is special form of servet, so JSP *is a* servet.